# Missing flash attributes after redirect in Spring MVC 4.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My controller methods look like the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleSaveRequest(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
                                Model model) {
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("myFlashAttr", "FOOBAR");
    return "redirect:/confirmationpage?myAttr=Some Value";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/confirmationpage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String confirmationPage(@RequestParam String myAttr,
                               @ModelAttribute("myFlashAttr") String flashAttr,
                                Model model) {
    logger.info("Param: " + myAttr);
    logger.info("FlashAttr: " + flashAttr);
    // Do Some stuff
    return "path/to/confirmation.jsp";
}
```

I was originally using Spring 4.0 and this was working as expected. When I was redirected to the confirmation page I had `myAttr = "Some Value"` and `flashAttr = "FOOBAR"`. However after upgrading to Spring 4.3 `flashAttr` was empty string (ie `myAttr = "Some Value"` and `flashAttr = ""`).

After shooting in the dark for a bit I found that replacing the whitespace in the redirect URL with `"%20"` (ie `"redirect:/confirmationpage?myAttr=Some%20Value"`) did the trick. After making this change the log output was `myAttr = Some Valu"` and `flashAttr = FOOBAR` as expected.

So I have a few questions really:

1. What changed between Spring 4.0 and 4.3 that causes this problem?
2. Why would URL encoding cause problems with session attributes?
3. What is the "correct" way to handle URL encoding on redirects in Spring MVC 4.3? I was always under the impression that Spring handled this for me in the [UrlBasedViewResolver](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.3.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html) but now I am second-guessing that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging around I found [this issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12569) on the Spring JIRA. I was able to use the suggested workaround to solve my problem without having to handle any of the URL encoding myself. The redirect now works as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleSaveRequest(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
                                Model model) {
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("myFlashAttr", "FOOBAR");
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("myAttr", "Some Value");

    return "redirect:/confirmationpage?myAttr={myAttr}";
}
```

While the issue described did not exactly match my case, it seems that the answer to 2&3 are:

2. The `FlashMapManager` relies on a different encoding scheme than the URL encoder in RedirectView.
3. Using this workaround it forces Spring to use URIUtils to encode each query parameter value.

I still do not understand the answer to my main question of "What changed to cause this?" but for my purposes the posted workaround seems to do the trick.